# How can I reverse the order of pictures shown in a jQuery Cycle slideshow during playback?

Tags: jquery, reverse, jquery-cycle

So my question is pretty straight-forward. Say I have a slideshow running with 'fade' transitions with 10 pictures in total, and I have the typical next/prev buttons as well. The slideshow cycles automatically from image 1 to image 10. How can I make it possible for the user to reverse the playback order at any moment? For example, while watching image 6, the user clicks 'prev' (or a new button if necessary), and after going back to image 5, the slideshow continues with image 4, 3, 2...

Is this even possible? I read about and tried the 'rev' option in Cycle, but I couldn't make it work, and actually I'm not sure that its purpose is the one I need.

THank you for any ideas!

Comment: It's definitely possible. Do you have a particular slide show plugin that you're working with?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the 'Cycle' plugin. This is the function call:    [code]$("#slides").cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
  pause: 1,
  prev: '#prev',
  next: '#next',
  nowrap: true //no looping
 }); [/code]      The slideshow works perfect, I just need to add this functionallity

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source, it looks like the **rev** option is only for animations, which doesn't apply to fade. Here is the exact comment:

```
// causes animations to transition in reverse (for effects that support it such as scrollHorz/scrollVert/shuffle)
```

You may be looking for **backwards**:

```
// true to start slideshow at last slide and move backwards through the stack
```

Try setting that to true when you want to reverse the order.

**EDIT:** There is probably a better way to do this. In any case, here is one way. First, add a click handler to your button that calls some function:

```
function toggleDirection(){
    // replace your_slide_div with whatever your div is named
    $('.your_slide_div').cycle("toggleDirection");
}
```

Then in the cycle plugin JS file, look for the **handleArguments(cont, options, arg2)** function. In the switch statement, add a case:

```
case "toggleDirection":
        $(cont).data('cycle.opts').backwards = $(cont).data('cycle.opts').backwards ? false : true;
        if($(cont).data('cycle.opts').backwards)
            $(cont).data('cycle.opts').nextSlide = 
                $(cont).data('cycle.opts').nextSlide - 2 < 0 ? 
                $(cont).children().length - 1 : $(cont).data('cycle.opts').nextSlide - 2;
        else
            $(cont).data('cycle.opts').nextSlide = 
                $(cont).data('cycle.opts').nextSlide + 2 >= $(cont).children().length ? 
                0 : $(cont).data('cycle.opts').nextSlide + 2;
        return false;
```

**EDIT:** This case assumes that you are sliding through all your images. If you are using the **slideExpr** option, then this will cause problems.

Note that this toggles the direction, so clicking the button twice returns it to normal, if you only want it to reverse it, change the case to:

```
(cont).data('cycle.opts').backwards = true;
```

**EDIT:** Last one hopefully. In the plugin JS file, do a search for the following:

```
opts.nextSlide < opts.currSlide
```

Replace that specific selection with:

```
opts.currSlide == els.length - 1
```

Comment: Oops I missed that, thanks, I'll check it out. How can I change the 'backwards' option from 'false' to 'true' during runtime? Is it possible to do something like $("#slides").cycle({ backwards: 'true'}); in a 'click' event handler without having to set the rest of options again?

Comment: @ZDYN: I've tried with your method and it's not working either. I actually tried toggle one and the non-toggle one. I changed the plugin js file as you say and called the new handler with a 'click' event in the button, but nothing. Maybe there's something else that needs to be changed? Your method makes sense, though.

Comment: @ZYDN: I've just been able to test that the call to "toggleDirection" actually works. What it's not working (at least for me) is the code inside the 'case' statement that actually is supposed to change the direction.

Comment: Hmm, I just tested it, and it worked. However there was one problem. The plugin does not "refresh" until the next delay + fade. This means if you click the button to reverse the order, it will show the next image and **then** start to go in reverse. I'll take a look.

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong then... what type of plugin are you using? I'm using the compressed 'all' one (jquery.cycle.all.min.js). I'll try with an isolated example and see if I can make it work. Anyways, if you can figure out how to solve the problem that you mention, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Can you verify that the case you wrote in the **jquery.cycle.all.min.js** file is being called? Put an alert in there or something.

Comment: Assuming the case is actually being called, I've rewritten it in my answer. So try using my new edit and see how that works. Hope it helps!

Comment: I just tried, and still not working. Weird thing is when I click that button, it triggers the function that I have in the 'end' option of the slideshow, even if the current picture is not the last one. I can confirm that the case in the **jquery.cycle.all.min.js** file is called, I tested with an alert. I'm gonna try with a new project, just with a slideshow, and see if it works. I really appreciate your help ZDYN!

Comment: No problem. Wish we could have figured this out. Just for reference here is the jsFiddle I was working with (I used the basic example on the plugin website): http://jsfiddle.net/7DFzw/1/

Comment: @ZDYN: So I found out something weird. If I use the plugin code that you have in the jsfiddle, it works! If I use the plugin code that I downloaded from the Cycle website, it doesn't work! The only difference I can see is the version, yours is 2.88 and mine is 2.94. The code inside the 'case "toggleDirection":' is the same in both, so for me the only explanation is that either there's something wrong in the version I have (2.94) or there's something else to be changed in the plugin apart from adding the new 'case' that I'm missing. The rest of the code is the same you use. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7DFzw/2/) with version 2.94. It still seems to work. What other options are you setting when you first call cycle?

Comment: @ZYDN: I think I just figured out what's going on. The problem comes when using the 'nowrap:true' option that I use in my slideshow. When I set it to `nowrap:false`, your code works! However, in my case I need the 'nowrap' set to true, because I don't want the slideshow to loop, I want to trigger an event at the end of the last slide (a function in the 'end' option) to take the user to another page, and with the 'nowrap' set to false, that event is not triggered. Is there any other way to accomplish this or to change your code to work with the 'nowrap' set to 'true'?

Comment: I think I've found the reason. The author checks for the end condition by checking if the next slide index is less than the current one (i.e. 0 - which would be a wrap - is less than 4 - if there are 5 images). Quite a naive check. Anyway, I'll update my answer in a second with the fix.

Comment: @ZDYN: It works now, but I've seen a strange behavior. With the `nowrap` set to false, everything is perfect, like before. However, when it's set to true, if you click the 'toggle' button once while watching the slideshow, it goes backwards fine, but instead of stopping in the first slide, it fades once more to the last slide kind of looping), and then stops. This could be a problem for what I need, since I need to be able to detect both ends of the slideshow to trigger a redirect to another page depending on what end the slideshow reaches...

Comment: @Albert R, right now the code only considers reaching that particular slide (the last one) "the end". If you want it to stop on the first slide when it goes backwards, change that selection to `((opts.currSlide == els.length - 1 && !opts.backwards) || (opts.currSlide == 0 && opts.backwards))`

Comment: @Albert R, in any case, regardless of which one you choose, the end condition **will** get triggered. Either on the "last slide" forwards/backwards in the first case, or "last slide" going forwards and "first slide" going backwards in the comment above.

Comment: @Albert R, apparently I didn't read the very last part of your comment. Detecting which end it stops on will be tricky since you only pass in one function for the end option.

Comment: @ZDYN: It works perfectly now!!! I did the last change you told me and now the behavior is exactly what I wanted! For your last comment, I think that it's actually the easiest part, compared to what you have done ;). To detect what end the slideshow stops on I only need to use the `opts.currSlide` property triggered in the `after` event, and see if it's 0 (first slide) or X-1 (where X is total number of slides). Well, I really appreciate your help, you have been awesome and without your help I would have never acomplished this! Thanks a lot!